# How does the Time Delay (m.delay) method work in Gekko

Tags: gekko

I read the Time Delay method in APMonitor, and used it along with the m.Intermediate method in Gekko as given in the code below. I have two questions and appreciate your help:
First) According to `m.delay(B_SOC_initial, B_SOC_Prev, 1)`, I expect that `B_SOC_Prev[1]` is equal to `B_SOC_initial[0]`, but it is equal to zero (Please see the attached image). I do not know where I am wrong. I appreciate your advice.
Second) I defined a simple objective function as `c[i] = Generation` which maximizes the sum of `c[i]` values. I need to have the optimum value of the objective function, but the result shows the sum of all values, not the optimum value. The expected objective function value is 103000, but it shows 309000 (Please the attached image).In other words, the objective function gets back the the sum of `c[i]`'s in all iterations, not the optimum run's case.
Thank you so much for your help.

[image]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

#Battery Specifications
Battery_capacity=589200 #kW-h
Battery_Initial_capacity=117840

n=3
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0, n - 1, n)

Demand =m.Param([0,46258,46952])
Generation =m.Param([0,53000,50000])

B_ch = m.Var(lb=0)
B_disch = m.Var(lb=0)

B_SOC_Prev= m.Var(value=Battery_Initial_capacity)
B_SOC_initial=m.Intermediate(B_SOC_Prev+B_ch-B_disch)
m.delay(B_SOC_initial, B_SOC_Prev, 1)

m.Equations([Generation + B_disch - B_ch == Demand,
             B_disch * B_ch <= 0,
             ]
            )

c = [None]*(n)
for i in range(n):
    c[i] = Generation

m.Maximize(sum(c))

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-8', \
                    'minlp_integer_leaves 2']
m.options.SOLVER   = 1
m.options.IMODE    = 6

# m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp=False)

print("Obj. Value=",-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)

for i in range(n):
    print("B_ch[{}]={} B_disch[{}]={} B_SOC_initial[{}]={}  B_SOC_Prev[{}]={}".format(i,B_ch[i],i,B_disch[i], i,B_SOC_initial[i],i,B_SOC_Prev[i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an initialization issue with using an intermediate variable and the time-delay model. Try using `m.Var()` types for both:

```py
B_SOC_Prev= m.Var(value=Battery_Initial_capacity)
B_SOC_initial=m.Var(value=Battery_Initial_capacity)
m.Equation(B_SOC_initial==B_SOC_Prev+B_ch-B_disch)
m.delay(B_SOC_initial, B_SOC_Prev, 1)
```

The `B_SOC_Prev[1]` is no longer zero.

```
B_ch[0]=0.0 B_disch[0]=0.0 B_SOC_initial[0]=117840.0  B_SOC_Prev[0]=117840.0
B_ch[1]=6742.0 B_disch[1]=0.0 B_SOC_initial[1]=124582.0  B_SOC_Prev[1]=117840.0
B_ch[2]=3048.0 B_disch[2]=0.0 B_SOC_initial[2]=127630.0  B_SOC_Prev[2]=124582.0
```

Additional information on the time delay model is in the [documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/TimeDelay).

For issue #2, use `m.Maximize(Generation)` instead of `m.Maximize(sum(c))`. This gives the correct objective function of `103000` because `gekko` automatically sums the values across the time horizon for that parameter. Note that it is currently a `m.Param()` type so the optimizer does not adjust the `Generation` values.

Here is a complete script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

#Battery Specifications
Battery_capacity=589200 #kW-h
Battery_Initial_capacity=117840

n=3
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0, n - 1, n)

Demand =m.Param([0,46258,46952])
Generation =m.Param([0,53000,50000])

B_ch = m.Var(lb=0)
B_disch = m.Var(lb=0)

B_SOC_Prev= m.Var(value=Battery_Initial_capacity)
B_SOC_initial=m.Var(value=Battery_Initial_capacity)
m.Equation(B_SOC_initial==B_SOC_Prev+B_ch-B_disch)
m.delay(B_SOC_initial, B_SOC_Prev, 1)

m.Equations([Generation + B_disch - B_ch == Demand,
             B_disch * B_ch <= 0,
             ]
            )

m.Maximize(Generation)

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-8', \
                    'minlp_integer_leaves 2']
m.options.SOLVER   = 1
m.options.IMODE    = 6

# m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp=True)

print("Obj. Value=",-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)

for i in range(n):
    print(f"B_ch[{i}]={B_ch[i]} " + 
          f"B_disch[{i}]={B_disch[i]} " +
          f"B_SOC_initial[{i}]={B_SOC_initial[i]} " +
          f"B_SOC_Prev[{i}]={B_SOC_Prev[i]}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much John, your response is very helpful. I already read the link which you kindly shared here. I also noticed that gekko sums up the objective values across the time horizon. I have just a question about the assignment of initial value for both variables. I wonder that the Equation 'm.Equation(B_SOC_initial==B_SOC_Prev+B_ch-B_disch)' does not calculate the initial value of the 'B_SOC_initial' based on the initial value of 'B_SOC_Prev'? of course, I checked and noticed that it did not calculate.  Once again, thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Correct - gekko doesn't calculate the equations on the first node of the horizon because those values are typically fixed as an initial value problem. If you need more control, use `IMODE=3` and define the equations for the time horizon explicitly instead of relying on `IMODE=6` automatic setup.